# Slightly wrong "member for" date in user profile

Tags: discussion, profile-page, dates

Not too important, but it helps determining if posts of new users are spam:

The profile for [this user](//superuser.com/users/63313/tad) claims this user joined two days ago, though its tooltip refers to about an hour:

[image: Joined 2 days ago according to profile]

The 10k tools [currently](//superuser.com/tools/flagged) show:

[image: Joined 1 hour ago according to 10k tools]

As the tooltip in my own profile (for a registered user) is correct, I guess the "2 days" is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "member for" field isn't a duration, it's a counter. He joined 1 hour ago at 23:39:08, which was yesterday ("now" is "00:39:08", after midnight). He's been a member for 2 days: yesterday and today

Comment: Wow, I never saw that

Comment: Aha, that makes the "joined" in the 10k tools perfect for its task.