# Should my profile say that I have been a member for a year, when I still have a few hours left to go?

Tags: discussion, yearling-badge

Whilst waiting for my yearling badge to show up, I checked my profile and saw that I was listed as having been a member for a year, though when I hovered over that text, it showed me what date-time I joined which was (approximately) 1 hour and 19 minutes less than a year.

See the attached screengrab showing my system clock at GMT Daylight Time, or UTC+1. This means that I took the screengrab at 13:57:20 UTC.

[image: screengrab of my profile]

I appreciate that I had been a member for a year to the nearest day, but if we are able to be more accurate than that, then shouldn't be be doing so? If nothing else, it would be easier to see when the yearling badge was due to be awarded.

Comment: I think it goes by a UTC year...

Comment: So, it took you 8 days to post the screenshot...? It's one year plus more than a week today.

Comment: Related: [Slightly wrong “member for” date in profile for unregistered user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75087/slightly-wrong-member-for-date-in-profile-for-unregistered-user).

Comment: Wow, not sure why I got 5 downvotes. It was just a question, next time if I think I see something that seems strange to me I won't bother asking!

Comment: @Grezzo Your question was downvoted because you suggested a change to the site ("if we are able to be more accurate than that, then shouldn't be be doing so?") which most people disagree with. That's how Meta works. Reputation isn't important here. It's not personal, it doesn't reflect upon you, so don't worry about it.

Comment: Never has inconsequential been so painful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is most certainly by design, and I agree with it.

As in every other activity, a *day* begins at 00:00 on SO.

If your mother gave birth to you at 15:00, does that mean people can't congratulate you in the morning?

Comment: Yes. Yes it does. Though most people don't like my 11PM birthday parties.

Comment: As an 23:04 PST baby, I ensure that I list my birthday appropriately depending on where I am currently in the world.

Comment: Well, and there are timezones and daylight saving time and leap seconds...OW, OW, stop hitting me...

Answer (score 4):

There are many examples of rounding-off like this in the StackExchange UI. One that I frequently notice is reputation rounding: if you have a large-enough rep,  SE will round to the nearest hundred or thousand in some places, sometimes rounding up. Here's an example I just hunted down:

Here's what shows right now on  one of Arjan's answers,

[image]

But here's what you see on his profile at the same time:

[image]

Comment: Interesting, [I joined at 00:00:00Z](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TmCa2.png) ;-)